# How to call a iframe in a panel in firefox extension

Tags: iframe, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I am trying to create a extension in Firefox using sdk addon. What i want to do is to call an iframe inside a panel.

I have already created the extension for chrome and now i am trying to do it for firefox.

I have a facebook login in the iframe. Once i click on the sign in button the iframe just goes blank. If I log in before hand then also the extension doesnt work. It is as if it can't access the session.

Here is the code of my main.js file.

```
var { ToggleButton } = require('sdk/ui/button/toggle');
var panels = require("sdk/panel");
var data = require("sdk/self").data;
var {Cc, Ci} = require("chrome");
var tabs = require("sdk/tabs");
var title=tabs.activeTab.title;

var button = ToggleButton({
  id: "my-button",
  label: "my button",
  icon: {
    "16": "./logo1.png",
    "32": "./logo1.png",
    "64": "./logo1.png"
  },
  onChange: handleChange
});

var panel = panels.Panel({
width:450,
height:400,              

  contentURL: data.url("popup.html"),
      onHide: handleHide
});

function handleChange(state) {
  if (state.checked) {
    panel.show({
      position: button
    });
  }
}

function handleHide() {
  button.state('window', {checked: false});
}
```

here is the code of my main javascript file that calls the iframe

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
document.body.style.display = 'block';
    var ur='xyz';   
        var frame = document.createElement('iframe');
        var frame_url = 'https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/page-mod';
        frame.setAttribute('width', '100%');
        frame.setAttribute('height', '100%');
//      frame.setAttribute('margin', '-10%');
        frame.setAttribute('frameborder', 'none');
        frame.setAttribute('id', 'rtmframe');
        $('body').height(450).width(400);           
            frame.setAttribute('src', frame_url);
            document.body.appendChild(frame);
             $('iframe#rtmframe').load(function() {
       $('#loadImg').hide();
    });

        });
```

This is not the actual link i am trying to open. Can anyone suggest what i can do differently. or point me to github code that might be doing the same thing.